# magento controller action

Tags: magento

I have created the following class on my module

```
class Mage_Chargeagent_PaymentupdateController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        echo "im here";
        die();
    }
}
```

it is located under local\Company\Chargeagent\controllers\PaymentupdateController.php

when im trying to navigate to http://www.xxx.com/index.php/chargeagent/paymentupdate im not getting to the correct action , what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: That's a violent action :-) `echo "Hello. My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father."; die();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class name should be `Company_Chargeagent_PaymentupdateController`

```
class Company_Chargeagent_PaymentupdateController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        echo "im here";
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your config.xml? Also did you add /app/etc/modules/Company_Chargeagent.xml?